# Making a barchart + line in a single graph, without the bars being centered in the middle of the graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Background:** Confusing header, I know. However, I hope the graph examples below can help.
I have this graph:

[image]

However, I dont like the bars being centered in the middle of the graph. It kind of makes the graph harder to read.

**Goal**: Instead I want something like this:

[image]

Where the bars are not floating in the middle of the graph, but instead planted just above the x-axis. I have tried multiple things with my code below, however, it cant get ggplot to work with me.

Any advice would be appreciated!

**Reproducible code** The graph i plotted in the beginning can be constructed with (i have excluded some of the dates in order for the data.frame to be small enough so that I can copy it into this question:

```
library(ggplot2)
df = structure(list(TradeDate = structure(c(1564617600, 1564704000, 
                                            1564963200, 1565049600, 1565136000, 1565222400, 1565308800, 1565568000, 
                                            1565654400, 1565740800, 1565827200, 1565913600, 1566172800, 1566259200, 
                                            1566345600, 1566432000, 1566518400, 1566777600, 1566864000, 1566950400, 
                                            1567036800, 1567123200, 1567382400, 1567468800, 1567555200, 1567641600, 
                                            1567728000, 1567987200, 1568073600, 1568160000, 1568246400, 1568332800, 
                                            1568592000, 1568678400, 1568764800, 1568851200, 1568937600, 1569196800, 
                                            1569283200, 1569369600, 1569456000, 1569542400, 1569801600, 1569888000, 
                                            1569974400, 1570060800, 1570147200, 1570406400, 1570492800, 1570579200, 
                                            1570665600, 1570752000, 1571011200, 1571097600, 1571184000, 1571270400, 
                                            1571356800, 1571616000, 1571702400, 1571788800, 1571875200, 1571961600, 
                                            1572220800, 1572307200, 1572393600, 1572480000, 1572566400, 1572825600, 
                                            1572912000, 1572998400, 1573084800, 1573171200, 1573430400, 1573516800, 
                                            1573603200, 1573689600, 1573776000, 1574035200, 1574121600, 1574208000, 
                                            1574294400, 1574380800, 1574640000, 1574726400, 1574812800, 1574899200, 
                                            1574985600, 1575244800, 1575331200, 1575417600, 1575504000, 1575590400, 
                                            1575849600, 1575936000, 1576022400, 1576108800, 1576195200, 1576454400, 
                                            1576540800, 1576627200, 1576713600, 1576800000, 1577059200, 1577404800, 
                                            1577664000, 1577836800, 1577923200, 1578009600, 1578268800, 1578355200, 
                                            1578441600, 1578528000, 1578614400, 1578873600, 1578960000, 1579046400, 
                                            1579132800, 1579219200, 1579478400, 1579564800, 1579651200, 1579737600, 
                                            1579824000, 1580083200, 1580169600, 1580256000, 1580342400, 1580428800, 
                                            1580688000, 1580774400, 1580860800, 1580947200, 1581033600, 1581292800, 
                                            1581379200, 1581465600, 1581552000, 1581638400, 1581897600, 1581984000, 
                                            1582070400, 1582156800, 1582243200, 1582502400, 1582588800, 1582675200, 
                                            1582761600, 1582848000, 1583107200, 1583193600, 1583280000, 1583366400, 
                                            1583452800, 1583712000, 1583798400, 1583884800, 1583971200, 1584057600, 
                                            1584316800, 1584403200, 1584489600, 1584576000, 1584662400, 1584921600, 
                                            1585008000, 1585094400, 1585180800, 1585267200, 1585526400, 1585612800, 
                                            1585699200, 1585785600, 1585872000, 1586131200, 1586217600, 1586304000, 
                                            1586822400, 1586908800, 1586995200, 1587081600, 1587340800, 1587427200, 
                                            1587513600, 1587600000, 1587686400, 1587945600, 1588032000, 1588118400, 
                                            1588204800, 1588291200, 1588550400, 1588636800, 1588723200, 1588809600, 
                                            1589155200, 1589241600, 1589328000, 1589414400, 1589500800, 1589760000, 
                                            1589846400, 1589932800, 1590364800, 1590451200, 1590537600, 1590624000, 
                                            1590710400, 1591056000, 1591142400, 1591228800, 1591574400, 1591660800, 
                                            1591747200, 1591833600, 1591920000, 1592179200, 1592265600, 1592352000, 
                                            1592438400, 1592524800, 1592784000, 1592870400, 1592956800, 1593043200, 
                                            1593129600, 1593388800, 1593475200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
                                            ), tzone = "UTC"), M7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                      NA, NA, 0.186070698489549, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.174780980869144, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.153113429181828, NA, NA, 
                                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), G = c(0.102950963306427, 0.111902425635715, 
                                                                                                            0.115106451707085, 0.114569666670424, 0.122388595864939, 0.114551280520846, 
                                                                                                            0.113155319144666, 0.114527987793056, 0.119162351004014, 0.123997543495646, 
                                                                                                            0.130987443738068, 0.136897884791, 0.123944052316217, 0.127383424125903, 
                                                                                                            0.121324975821324, 0.117258399710734, 0.116204741834938, 0.11885088841493, 
                                                                                                            0.125415736729673, 0.134950231993282, 0.130516568953604, 0.129746586367464, 
                                                                                                            0.127909271526176, 0.131250993804273, 0.125896528487707, 0.11973905251483, 
                                                                                                            0.123961281663863, 0.122042657473265, 0.122785255059344, 0.119841605858598, 
                                                                                                            0.12418213731745, 0.114360437212582, 0.115492513190912, 0.119902651903315, 
                                                                                                            0.122944518327251, 0.124644994069685, 0.125519804140568, 0.130876264140318, 
                                                                                                            0.131365830881852, 0.135977541505893, 0.129329549845017, 0.125302980372166, 
                                                                                                            0.120279979003203, 0.11917079904289, 0.12121950141301, 0.12439778105626, 
                                                                                                            0.124593476307828, 0.12468932440672, 0.124078625936983, 0.122026924383826, 
                                                                                                            0.117727501282582, 0.112537058063298, 0.114296023882317, 0.112409474061991, 
                                                                                                            0.106100784808972, 0.10405853363721, 0.104432013695369, 0.0996108274999974, 
                                                                                                            0.103576432752433, 0.108376153601936, 0.10613659788826, 0.103955591595455, 
                                                                                                            0.0966199992991874, 0.100268714966, 0.100416575473497, 0.105525303788234, 
                                                                                                            0.104239275020246, 0.0994653809740947, 0.0955643992717006, 0.0976013768957238, 
                                                                                                            0.0929338135499067, 0.0908474890807786, 0.0939973824935808, 0.0931733501390247, 
                                                                                                            0.0998453114761617, 0.101778097401663, 0.100474385014638, 0.100563729002441, 
                                                                                                            0.0993379273631683, 0.102116157078598, 0.0986116230564997, 0.101159906609472, 
                                                                                                            0.100971552032995, 0.10081101810235, 0.102190971902831, 0.101406914764034, 
                                                                                                            0.10053553796163, 0.0933267005127337, 0.0982331418729998, 0.0981840173387494, 
                                                                                                            0.093929300197465, 0.0954472118170791, 0.0973128505504601, 0.0965749558542103, 
                                                                                                            0.0977514960509353, 0.0979188868605533, 0.0950382624915921, 0.0988765553406277, 
                                                                                                            0.097613112854407, 0.0950622715158606, 0.0901322280867909, 0.0914188972262535, 
                                                                                                            0.0926937890218228, 0.0888422660030223, 0.085475676780949, NA, 
                                                                                                            0.0908515305182729, 0.0984811995715679, 0.100736332889717, 0.0994678761145788, 
                                                                                                            0.0967265256686255, 0.0926830946774334, 0.0922422293121505, 0.090622675166798, 
                                                                                                            0.090738610449321, 0.0960402489412668, 0.0957960813407729, 0.0950618355761103, 
                                                                                                            0.0961249049879837, 0.0976506457941844, 0.100562346873119, 0.10302561747182, 
                                                                                                            0.10492818038862, 0.11308364003771, 0.111140384800535, 0.110093002809203, 
                                                                                                            0.111680261263197, 0.11340952395467, 0.11422742793743, 0.110231799603694, 
                                                                                                            0.106200833803754, 0.104951435870609, 0.108895288052459, 0.108571368983049, 
                                                                                                            0.107643665416751, 0.106236143912607, 0.106676743891322, 0.108310266149225, 
                                                                                                            0.108131534142701, 0.109053392509317, 0.109251537089543, 0.113243956200389, 
                                                                                                            0.115800045899643, 0.11927059092712, 0.117564141616849, 0.11461971104665, 
                                                                                                            0.119662782263277, 0.123758257045154, 0.127840261139008, 0.124389755174952, 
                                                                                                            0.127432022144506, 0.129398129170195, 0.135093092289825, 0.148820591514698, 
                                                                                                            0.140969030364669, 0.142706719044991, 0.144327390993928, 0.124531941844018, 
                                                                                                            0.11925883652687, 0.115225076774297, 0.100789141102098, 0.0850573904668294, 
                                                                                                            0.0842192839196936, 0.0868678865613668, 0.0716171481320629, 0.0630183039187272, 
                                                                                                            0.0451626667247753, 0.0533619594649604, 0.054157175691997, 0.0501656821895386, 
                                                                                                            0.0515473263742462, 0.0586182208990103, 0.0572143161300601, 0.0493465080388473, 
                                                                                                            0.041528900501516, 0.0386029524116141, 0.0459901757764132, 0.0509121099411166, 
                                                                                                            0.0519108978022358, 0.0516505883209034, 0.0482325375612605, 0.0509196112725313, 
                                                                                                            0.0457309998666454, 0.0469223279716312, 0.0520674691342883, 0.053463425098647, 
                                                                                                            0.0558592543660823, 0.0591073220312325, 0.0638047468731654, 0.0687681553606982, 
                                                                                                            0.0644509042665515, 0.0672924002206374, 0.0664019861891486, 0.067624058196437, 
                                                                                                            0.0696330414320328, 0.0715163868413125, 0.0763846419374143, 0.077467848087492, 
                                                                                                            0.0804259035337199, 0.0782983892966253, 0.0749934812118791, 0.076561903174488, 
                                                                                                            0.0776441410960671, 0.075680252994631, 0.0732271695532569, 0.0753582300794893, 
                                                                                                            0.0784394348576695, 0.0745837416720095, 0.0735631451399277, 0.0713513956728399, 
                                                                                                            0.0706776422310245, 0.0747956086696676, 0.0737504691139788, 0.0831768528899659, 
                                                                                                            0.0846465764020813, 0.0869777957869674, 0.084020836986888, 0.0851776914283767, 
                                                                                                            0.0894083769120367, 0.0879633110194116, 0.0924045558365151, 0.0884895343802038, 
                                                                                                            0.0858297296793646, 0.0930684850379403, 0.092938308580224, 0.0906009033812057, 
                                                                                                            0.0922202626587521)), row.names = 331:557, class = "data.frame")
get_default_colors <- function(){
  colors <- c(
    # hatch and bloom
    rgb(0, 69, 123, maxColorValue = 255), 
    rgb(27, 182, 234, maxColorValue = 255),
    rgb(193, 215, 47, maxColorValue = 255),
    rgb(247, 143, 30, maxColorValue = 255),
    rgb(141, 218, 244, maxColorValue = 255),
    rgb(36, 167, 143, maxColorValue = 255),
    rgb(204, 28, 85, maxColorValue = 255),
    rgb(91, 57, 0, maxColorValue = 255),
    rgb(124, 0, 64, maxColorValue = 255),
    rgb(103, 101, 47, maxColorValue = 255),
    
    # other colors
    rgb(229, 236, 246, maxColorValue = 255),
    rgb(127, 162, 189, maxColorValue = 255),
    rgb(64, 116, 156, maxColorValue = 255)
  )
  
  return(colors)
}

default_colors <- get_default_colors()


ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = df, aes(x = as.Date(TradeDate), y = M7), fill = default_colors[1], width = 20) +  # Use first custom color for bars
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x = as.Date(TradeDate), y = G), color = default_colors[2], size = 1) +  # Use second custom color for line 
  theme_bw() + 
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "M", 
    limits = c(-0.5, 0.25),  # Set y-axis limits
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~., name = "G")
  ) +
  #labs(title = GainAsset, x = "") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 0.5),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.position = 'right',
        plot.title = element_text(size = 14),  
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 12)) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "3 months", date_labels = "%b-%y")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, when adding a secondary axis (and plotting values) this relies on a formula mapping values of your second y-variable to the first. Here, to make the line reach the bottom at its minimum value, you can create a `pseudo_G` variable that equals `G - min(G)` (which is zero at its lowest point). The reverse formula gives the transformed y axis variables:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  mutate(pseudo_G = G - min(G, na.rm = TRUE)) |> 
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = as.Date(TradeDate), y = M7), fill = default_colors[1], width = 20) +  # Use first custom color for bars
  geom_line(aes(x = as.Date(TradeDate), y = pseudo_G), color = default_colors[2], size = 1) +  # Use second custom color for line 
  theme_bw() + 
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "M", 
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~. + min(df$G, na.rm = TRUE), name = "G")
  ) +
  #labs(title = GainAsset, x = "") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 0.5),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.position = 'right',
        plot.title = element_text(size = 14),  
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 12)) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "3 months", date_labels = "%b-%y")
```

[image]